# Sending a file chunk WITH meta data over a WebRTC Data Channel

Tags: javascript, webrtc, filereader

I have a file chunking operation that splits a file via File Reader into slices which are read via `readAsArrayBuffer`. I would like to send those chunks one at a time over my data channel WITH meta information attached (a chunk id, for instance). Like:

```
// Build chunk wrapper
var block = {
  chunkId: id,
  data: buffer
};

// Send the chunk to peer
channel.send(JSON.stringify(block));
```

Now when I send that data as is demonstrated above the data in the ArrayBuffer `buffer` is lost. I would like to emphasize I'm not having any trouble sending data over my data channel.

I would like to know how I can send that data with its associated meta information so that the file chunks can be reassembled in the correct order on the other side?

Do I need to do something like make an ArrayBuffer with two sub arrays, one with the meta information, and the other with the actual data or is there a simpler way?

Comment: I'm currently having a similar problem and was wondering if you ever came up with a solution?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can solve this, but basically you'll need to serialize, encode and deserialize, decode your data.
If you want to send your metadata with the data, you'll need to either serialize both to a uint8array or to a string, and do the inverted operation on the receiver side.
For example Sharefest utilizes a TLV protocol: https://github.com/Peer5/ShareFest/blob/master/core/protocol/BinaryProtocol.js